# React vscode-webview-ui-toolkit button not showing icon

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, icons, vscode-extensions

I am developing an extension for vscode with React and using the WebUi Toolkit library (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-webview-ui-toolkit) for components. I want to add a "save" icon to my button.

I have followed the documentation to add my button in react (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-webview-ui-toolkit/tree/main/src/react#use-oninput-instead-of-onchange-to-handle-keystrokes).

And I followed the other part of the documentation to add an icon (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-webview-ui-toolkit/blob/main/src/button/README.md#start-icon).

I have also looked for the save icon on the codicons website (https://microsoft.github.io/vscode-codicons/dist/codicon.html).

So the resulting code is:

```js
import { VSCodeButton } from '@vscode/webview-ui-toolkit/react';    

<VSCodeButton >
    Save
    <span slot="start" className="codicon codicon-save"></span>
</VSCodeButton>
```

But the icon is not showing.
How to add the icon to the button?

Answer (score 0):

Your code and the samples provided by the Toolkit documentation use certain CSS classes to style the icons. In your case, if the classes `codicon` and `codicon-save` aren't found, it won't work as expected.

First, you'll need to properly install the [Codicons package](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-codicons). Make sure you are installing this for the React app specifically and not the root of the extension (assuming your extension is based on the [Webview UI Toolkit React sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-webview-ui-toolkit-samples/tree/main/frameworks/hello-world-react-vite), this would be at the `webview-ui` level).

Then, like in Microsoft's provided [webview Codicons sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/webview-codicons-sample), you must include a style sheet `<link>` in your webview provider's HTML content, as shown [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/22d5639ff5c1d88f144c057fc3d29cc9dfd99d62/webview-codicons-sample/src/extension.ts#L34) (note that this is using the deprecated `vscode-codicons`, but you'll need `@vscode/codicons`). In your case, you'll likely want something like this in your webview panel provider (in the main extension `src`, not the `webview-ui` React app):

```js
import { Uri } as vscode from "vscode";

private _getWebviewContent(webview: Webview, extensionUri: Uri) {
  const codiconsUri = webview.asWebviewUri(
    Uri.joinPath(
      extensionUri,
      `webview-ui`,
      'node_modules',
      '@vscode',
      'codicons',
      'dist',
      'codicon.css',
    )
  );

  return `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${codiconsUri}">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
  `;
}
```

This way, the React app will have access to the necessary CSS classes to render the desired icons properly with the code you provided.

You will also need to add that same directory to the allowed local resources in your webview options, otherwise you'll likely get a `401: Unauthorized` error in trying to retrieve the style sheet:

```js
import { Uri } as vscode from "vscode";

this._webviewView.webview.options = {
  enableScripts: true,
  localResourceRoots: [
    Uri.joinPath(this._extensionUri, "out"),
    Uri.joinPath(this._extensionUri, "webview-ui/build"),

    // Must explicitly allow webview access to that style sheet
    Uri.joinPath(this._extensionUri, "webview-ui/node_modules/@vscode/codicons/dist"),
  ],
};
```